# LLVM based project lib dependencies for CMake on windows

Tags: cmake, llvm, mingw32, llvm-3.0

This has been asked here before but I couldn't find a solution which works for me. 
[Sample CMakeLists.txt file for LLVM project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8286768/sample-cmakelists-txt-file-for-llvm-project) - This was the original question.

However, there are a couple of issues I am facing when making a project with LLVM.

Platform: Windows 7
Compiler: MingW

1) Firstly, I am using the svn version of llvm which is currently at 3.1. Currently, Binaries for MingW are not present for llvm 3.0 too so I decided to go with the latest itself and build it with mingw. So although the build works fine, I cannot seem to find the llvm-config perl script in the bin folder. I tried searching the entire dir yet I can only find an llvm-config folder and a dependencies file.

2) I tried building llvm for Visual studio 2010 yet that didn't work with cmake so I had to use MingW.

3) Now, this is sequence in which I add libs to CMake - 
LLVMXCoreInfo

LLVMMipsAsmPrinter
LLVMMipsCodeGen
LLVMMipsInfo
LLVMMBlazeAsmPrinter
LLVMMBlazeCodeGen
LLVMMBlazeInfo
LLVMLinker
LLVMipo
LLVMInterpreter
LLVMInstrumentation
LLVMJIT
LLVMExecutionEngine

LLVMMC
LLVMBitWriter
LLVMX86Disassembler
LLVMX86AsmParser
LLVMX86AsmPrinter
LLVMX86CodeGen
LLVMX86Info
LLVMAsmParser
LLVMARMAsmParser
LLVMMCParser
LLVMARMAsmPrinter
LLVMARMCodeGen
LLVMARMInfo
LLVMArchive
LLVMBitReader

LLVMSelectionDAG

LLVMAsmPrinter
LLVMCodeGen
LLVMScalarOpts
LLVMInstCombine
LLVMTransformUtils
LLVMipa
LLVMAnalysis
LLVMTarget
LLVMMC
LLVMCore

LLVMSupport

imagehlp
psapi
m

4) However, adding InitializeNativeTarget(), starts giving me linking errors which I think come because of the dependencies not being in right order.

5) I want to use the llvm_map_components_to_libraries(REQ_LLVM_LIBRARIES jit native) and hence I added this to my CMakeLists.txt 
INCLUDE(cmake/LLVM-Config.cmake)

However, this doesn't work. CMake Error at cmake/LLVM-Config.cmake:141 (message):
  Library `jit' not found in list of llvm libraries.

Now, the question is really too long but I basically wanted to ask what is the best way to do this in CMake. Could someone post the entire thing (for windows).
Also, is there a way to build it for VS 2010. I tried the instructions on CLang site but those gave me this error in CMake.

" string sub-command REGEX, mode MATCH needs at least 5 arguments total to command."

I really need some help figuring out how to get dependencies to work in llvm and for it to build with VS. I would really appreciate some help.

Comment: What version of CMake are you using? the CMake build of Clang and LLVM with VS2010 is tested continuously, so it should work.

Comment: @MichaelSpencer I used Visual Studio 11 Win64 as CMake generator string and VS Express for desktop to build clang and its working. As MS extensions to C++ standard library are off limits, I use it with SUA gcc c++stdlib mingw-W64 ld -m i386pep